# git clone --recurse-submodules recording absolute paths for submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

`git clone --recurse-submodules` is recording absolute paths for submodules.

That is, when I clone the parent directory, the value of `gitdir` in the .git folder of each submodule is recording the absolute path of the submodule, which makes it impossible for me to move the newly cloned directory without all the submodules becoming unusable.

In the original repo, where i first made the submodules the .git file looks like:

`gitdir: ../../.git/modules/data/scta-codices`

but after cloning into a new directory with 
git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:scta/scta-rdf.git the .git file looks like:

`gitdir: /Users/username/Desktop/scta-rdf/.git/modules/data/scta-projectfiles`

Any ideas of what's going wrong?

Here is what the .gitmodules file looks like in the parent directory:

```
[submodule "data/scta-projectfiles"]
    path = data/scta-projectfiles
    url = https://github.com/scta/scta-projectfiles
    branch = master
[submodule "data/scta-codices"]
    path = data/scta-codices
    url = https://github.com/scta/scta-codices
    branch = master
[submodule "data/scta-quotations"]
    path = data/scta-quotations
    url = https://github.com/scta/scta-quotations
    branch = master
[submodule "data/lombardpress-lists"]
    path = data/lombardpress-lists
    url = https://github.com/lombardpress/lombardpress-lists
    branch = master
[submodule "data/scta-rdf-schema"]
    path = data/scta-rdf-schema
    url = https://github.com/scta/scta-rdf-schema
    branch = master
[submodule "data/scta-people"]
    path = data/scta-people
    url = https://github.com/scta/scta-people
    branch = master
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. Have you found any solution? I just discovered the same issue on my setup.

Comment: And I just found out that doing `git submodule init` followed by `git submodule update` creates relative paths once the cloning is done (but during cloning absolute paths are set in the .git files of each submodule).

Comment: hmm, no solution yet. it's an odd behavior. when cloning on the desktop of my mac, absolute paths we're created. but when I cloned on my linux server, the desired relative paths were created. I'm not sure why I'm getting different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually [fixed in Git v2.8.3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8eaa0ba98b3bd9cb9035eba184a2d9806d30b27), released in May 2016. Although the commit message might not look like it, and there was no release note entry either, this is the actual fix (I verified it by bisecting the git with itself).

See also the [mailing list discussion which led to the fix of this bug](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=145932862024551).

The problematic Git version is still present in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, for example.